# Working with Form Object and nested attributes: Couldn't find JoinTableRecord with ID=1 for Parent with ID=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, nested-attributes

I'm working on a form object where I build and save an instance of `Service`, but I'm having a hard time building and saving nested records.

A `Service` `has_one` `features_set` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for it.

A `FeaturesSet` `accepts_nested_attributes_for` `:crown_items`, which is a join table between that model and `Crown`.

features_set.rb

```
class FeaturesSet < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :crown_items
  has_many :crowns, through: :crown_items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :crown_items
end
```

crown_item.rb

```
class CrownItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :features_set
  belongs_to :crown
end
```

crown.rb

```
class Crown < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :crown_items
  has_many :features_sets, :through => :crown_items
end
```

This is what my `ServiceForm` form object looks like:

```
class ServiceForm
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks

  attr_accessor   :crowns
                  
  before_validation :build_features_set

  def initialize(params = {})
    super(params)
  end

  def save
    return false if invalid?

    service.save
  end

  def service
    @service ||= Service.new
  end

  def build_features_set
    service.build_features_set(
      crown_items_attributes: crowns
    )
  end
end
```

On initialization, this is what the `crowns` param looks like:

```
{0=>{:quantity=>1, :crown_id=>1}, 1=>{:quantity=>5, :crown_id=>2}}
```

When I try to save the `service` instance, I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find CrownItem with ID=1 for FeaturesSet with ID=
```

and now if I access the `crowns` params again, it looks like this:

```
{0=>{:quantity=>1, :crown_id=>1, "id"=>"1"}, 1=>{:quantity=>5, :crown_id=>2, "id"=>"1"}}
```

It looks like it is creating the `crown_item` records as it's adding an `ID` to them (albeit they both have the same ID), but I don't really understand what the error is telling me.